# How to get the 'name' property on 'option' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="/static/images/legends/default.png" class="legend-icon">
    <option class="legend-icon" name="/static/images/legends/icon1.png">option1</option>
    <option class="legend-icon" name="/static/images/legends/icon2.png">option2</option>
    <option class="legend-icon" name="/static/images/legends/icon3.png">option3</option>
</select>
```

When the value of the combobox changes I want the newly chosen option's 'name'. Is this possible to be done? If yes, how? I tried this:

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
    alert(e.delegateTarget.name);
});
```

This alerts the 'name' of the 'select' tag. But I need the name of the 'option' tag. Any help?

Comment: That's not valid markup, and won't work well regardless of the method you choose. `options` don't have a `name` attribute (source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html) and even if they did, you're abusing it by using it to attach something that isn't a name. Consider a data attribute instead: `<option class="legend-icon" data-icon="/static/images/legends/icon3.png">option3</option>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the selected option and then find its name attribute value

```
$('select').change(function (e) {
    alert($(this).find(':selected').attr('name'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UpWwU/)

Comment: Thanks it works. But is it not available within the 'event' object?

Comment: @Praveen no the change event is triggered by the select element

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/HLYYB/

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
    console.log($('option:selected', this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).find('option:selected').attr('name'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xZf42/

Note: As @meagar mentioned in his comment to your question, `name` is not a standard attribute of `option` elements. Consider using custom attributes prefixed with `data-`:

```
<option class="legend-icon" data-name="/static/images/legends/icon1.png">
    option1
</option>
```